# How to fix Duplicate Resources error android studio

Tags: java, android

**My Code**

this my **build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.0"
    flavorDimensions"mode"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.research.home"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    productFlavors{
        sandbox{
            applicationId "com.research.home"
            resValue "string", "app_name", "Rumah Riset"
            buildConfigField "string", "MERCHANT_BASE_URL", "\"My Url Server/\""
            buildConfigField "string", "MERCHANT_CLIENT_KEY", "My client key kode"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    configurations {
        compile.exclude group: "junit", module: "junit"
    }

    android {
        lintOptions {
            checkReleaseBuilds false
            // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
            // but continue the build even when errors are found:
            abortOnError false
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0-alpha02'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.1'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.4.20"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'org.testng:testng:6.9.6'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:6.2.1'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:20.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:19.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:21.0.0'

    //picasso
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

    //circle image view library
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'

    //glide library
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'

    // Coroutines
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.5'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.5'

    // Retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.6.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.6.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.10.8'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.10.8'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-dash:2.10.8'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-hls:2.10.8'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-smoothstreaming:2.10.8'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.10.8'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:6.2.0'

    implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.1'

    //implementation 'com.github.naya-aastra:SkewPdfView:1.1'
    implementation 'com.github.kk121:File-Loader:1.2'

    //Neorophism
    //implementation 'com.github.4inodev:Neomorphic-FrameLayout-Android:1.03'

    //Tooltip
    implementation 'com.github.florent37:viewtooltip:1.2.2'

    //midtrans.com
    // For using the Midtrans Sandbox
    implementation 'com.midtrans:uikit:1.24.1-SANDBOX' // change the number to the latest version
    // For using the Midtrans Production
//    implementation 'com.midtrans:uikit:1.24.1' // change the number to the latest version


}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

how do i fix this error code

**this error code**

```
> Task :app:mergeSandboxDebugResources FAILED
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Duplicate resources","sources":[{"file":{"description":"string/app_name","path":"C:\\Users\\ASUS\\Downloads\\Documents\\android\\BuildTwo\\app\\src\\main\\res\\values\\strings.xml"}},{"file":{"description":"string/app_name","path":"C:\\Users\\ASUS\\Downloads\\Documents\\android\\BuildTwo\\app\\build\\generated\\res\\resValues\\sandbox\\debug\\values\\gradleResValues.xml"}}],"tool":"Resource and asset merger"}

Execution failed for task ':app:mergeSandboxDebugResources'.
> [string/app_name] C:\Users\ASUS\Downloads\Documents\android\BuildTwo\app\src\main\res\values\strings.xml  [string/app_name] C:\Users\ASUS\Downloads\Documents\android\BuildTwo\app\build\generated\res\resValues\sandbox\debug\values\gradleResValues.xml: 
Error: Duplicate resources
```

when I build the code it displays an error like this,

this my **string.xml**

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Research Home</string>
    <string name="already_have_account">Already Have Account ?</string>
    <string name="sign_in">Sign In</string>
    <string name="sign_up">Sign Up</string>
    <string name="full_name">Full Name</string>
    <string name="email">Email</string>
    <string name="password">Password</string>
    <string name="confirmation_password">Confirmation Password</string>
    <string name="choose_your_class">Choose Your Class</string>
    <string name="menu_home" translatable="false">Home</string>
    <string name="menu_chat" translatable="false">Chat</string>
    <string name="menu_profile" translatable="false">Profile</string>
    <string name="menu_payment" translatable="false">Payment</string>
    <string name="welcome_admin">Welcome, Admin</string>
    <string name="no_file_selected">No File Selected</string>
    <string name="pls_select_a_podcast">Please Select a Podcast</string>
    <string name="select_podcast">Select Podcast</string>
    <string name="upload">Upload</string>
    <string name="select_video">Select Video</string>
    <string name="please_select_a_video">Please Select a Video</string>
    <string name="question">Question</string>
    <string name="write_a_question" translatable="false">Write a Question</string>
    <string name="answer">Answer</string>
    <string name="answerAlpha" translatable="false">A</string>
    <string name="writeanswer" translatable="false">Write a Answer</string>
    <string name="answerBravo" translatable="false">B</string>
    <string name="answerCharlie" translatable="false">C</string>
    <string name="answerDelta" translatable="false">D</string>
    <string name="upload_quiz">Upload Quiz</string>
    <string name="edit_quiz">Edit Quiz</string>
    <string name="classess">Class</string>
    <string name="directss">Direct</string>
    <string name="pay">Pay</string>
    <string name="edit">Edit</string>
    <string name="delete">Delete</string>
    <string name="business_management" translatable="false">Business Management</string>
    <string name="enterpreneur" translatable="false">Enterpreneur</string>
    <string name="enrichment" translatable="false">Enrichment</string>
    <string name="click_to_play">Click to Play</string>


    <string-array name="Podcast_Path">
        <item>Select Podcast List</item>
        <item>Podcast1</item>
        <item>Podcast2</item>
        <item>Podcast3</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="Podcast_Edit_Path">
        <item>Podcast1</item>
        <item>Podcast2</item>
        <item>Podcast3</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="Video_Path">
        <item>Select Video Path</item>
        <item>Business Management Basic</item>
        <item>Business Management Middle Science</item>
        <item>Business Managemen Middle Social Science</item>
        <item>Business Management Advance Science</item>
        <item>Business Management Advance Social Science</item>
        <!-- Enterpreneur -->
        <item>Enterpreneur Basic</item>
        <item>Enterpreneur Middle Science</item>
        <item>Enterpreneur Middle Social Science</item>
        <item>Enterpreneur Advance Science</item>
        <item>Enterpreneur Advance Social Science</item>
        <!-- Enrichment -->
        <item>Enrichment Basic</item>
        <item>Enrichment Middle Science</item>
        <item>Enrichment Middle Social Science</item>
        <item>Enrichment Advance Science</item>
        <item>Enrichment Advance Social Science</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="Quiz_Path">
        <item>Select Quiz Path</item>
        <item>Business Management Quiz</item>
        <item>Enterpreneur Quiz</item>
        <item>Enrichment Quiz</item>
        <item>Video Path 3</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="Quiz_Path_Edit">
        <item>Business Management Quiz</item>
        <item>Enterpreneur Quiz</item>
        <item>Enrichment Quiz</item>
        <item>Video Path 3</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="Quiz_Num">
        <item>Select Quiz Number</item>
        <item>1</item>
        <item>2</item>
        <item>3</item>
        <item>4</item>
        <item>5</item>
        <item>6</item>
        <item>7</item>
        <item>8</item>
        <item>9</item>
        <item>10</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="Quiz_Theory">
        <item>Select Quiz Theory</item>
        <item>Quiz Theory 1</item>
        <item>Quiz Theory 2</item>
        <item>Quiz Theory 3</item>
        <item>Quiz Theory 4</item>
        <item>Quiz Theory 5</item>
        <item>Quiz Theory 6</item>

    </string-array>

    <string-array name="Video_Theory">
        <item>Select Video Theory</item>
        <item>Theory 1</item>
        <item>Theory 2</item>
        <item>Theory 3</item>
        <item>Theory 4</item>
        <item>Theory 5</item>
        <item>Theory 6</item>
        <item>Theory 7</item>
        <item>Theory 8</item>
        <item>Theory 9</item>
        <item>Theory 10</item>
        <item>Theory 11</item>
        <item>Theory 12</item>

    </string-array>

    <string-array name="Video_Edit_Path">
        <item>Business Management Basic</item>
        <item>Business Management Middle Science</item>
        <item>Business Managemen Middle Social Science</item>
        <item>Business Management Advance Science</item>
        <item>Business Management Advance Social Science</item>
        <!-- Enterpreneur -->
        <item>Enterpreneur Basic</item>
        <item>Enterpreneur Middle Science</item>
        <item>Enterpreneur Middle Social Science</item>
        <item>Enterpreneur Advance Science</item>
        <item>Enterpreneur Advance Social Science</item>
        <!-- Enrichment -->
        <item>Enrichment Basic</item>
        <item>Enrichment Middle Science</item>
        <item>Enrichment Middle Social Science</item>
        <item>Enrichment Advance Science</item>
        <item>Enrichment Advance Social Science</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="Video_Edit_Theory">
        <item>Theory 1</item>
        <item>Theory 2</item>
        <item>Theory 3</item>
        <item>Theory 4</item>
        <item>Theory 5</item>
        <item>Theory 6</item>
        <item>Theory 7</item>
        <item>Theory 8</item>
        <item>Theory 9</item>
        <item>Theory 10</item>
        <item>Theory 11</item>
        <item>Theory 12</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="Ebook_Path">
        <item>Select Ebook Path</item>
        <item>Business Management Basic</item>
        <item>Business Management Middle Science</item>
        <item>Business Managemen Middle Social Science</item>
        <item>Business Management Advance Science</item>
        <item>Business Management Advance Social Science</item>
        <!-- Enterpreneur -->
        <item>Enterpreneur Basic</item>
        <item>Enterpreneur Middle Science</item>
        <item>Enterpreneur Middle Social Science</item>
        <item>Enterpreneur Advance Science</item>
        <item>Enterpreneur Advance Social Science</item>
        <!-- Enrichment -->
        <item>Enrichment Basic</item>
        <item>Enrichment Middle Science</item>
        <item>Enrichment Middle Social Science</item>
        <item>Enrichment Advance Science</item>
        <item>Enrichment Advance Social Science</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="Ebook_Theory">
        <item>Select Ebook Theory</item>
        <item>Theory 1</item>
        <item>Theory 2</item>
        <item>Theory 3</item>
        <item>Theory 4</item>
        <item>Theory 5</item>
        <item>Theory 6</item>
        <item>Theory 7</item>
        <item>Theory 8</item>
        <item>Theory 9</item>
        <item>Theory 10</item>
        <item>Theory 11</item>
        <item>Theory 12</item>

    </string-array>
    <string name="theory">Theory</string>
    <string name="press_back_again">Press back again to Exit</string>
    <string name="email_is_required">Email can\'t be empty</string>
    <string name="password_is_required">Password can\'t be empty</string>
    <string name="fname_is_required">Name can\'t be empty</string>
    <string name="password_must_same">Confirm your password</string>
    <string name="password_character">Password must have 8 character or more</string>
    <string name="lang">English</string>
    <string name="scores">Scores</string>
    <string name="forgot_password">Forgot password?</string>
    <string name="basicexplain">Recommended for Beginner (the Basics of Scientists ) </string>
    <string name="middleexplain">Recommended for Middle ( the Middless of Scientists )</string>
    <string name="advanceexplain">Recommended for Advance ( the Advances of Scientists )</string>
    <string name="cancel">Cancel</string>
    <string name="change">Change</string>
</resources>
```

The error immediately points to the string that I created, but there is no error or duplicate in the string.

I've tried changing the app_name name and application id in build.gradle, but it still shows Duplicate resources

please help me for fix this code

Thank You :)

Comment: did you try to clean and rebuild project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there are duplicate strings resource named **app_name**:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Research Home</string> //here

sandbox{
            applicationId "com.research.home"
            resValue "string", "app_name", "Rumah Riset" //and here
```

To solve this issue, you could declare the `app_name` as empty in defaultConfig:

```
defaultConfig {
    resValue "string", "app_name", ""
    
}
```

Comment: like this bro? ``defaultConfig {
        resValue "string", "app_name", ""
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }``

it's same error duplicate

Comment: thanks i delete

`applicationId "com.research.home"
            resValue "string", "app_name", "Rumah Riset"`

Answer (score 2):

Error in this file `gradleResValues.xml`
try this **go to top bar**  `project` >>> `clean` and `rebuild` it

**cause of this error**
That's because Android considers the following to be the same when you reference in your layout.

Comment: after cleaning and rebuilding it nothing can change the error

Comment: thanks i deleted this `applicationId "com.research.home" \nresValue "string", "app_name", "Rumah Riset"`